# Unfortunately Application stopped in android emulator

Tags: android

I am having problem running the application in emulator. Every time I try to run the application it provide me the message "Unfortunately, hello has stopped working". I went through the answer for similar problem but none of them helped me.Below is my code:

Main activity.java

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    private Button btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    private TextView ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

    private EditText first =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);
    private EditText second =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listener();
    }


    private void listener()
    {
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            { 
                String txt1=first.getText().toString();
                int no1=Integer.parseInt(txt1);
                String txt2=second.getText().toString();
                int no2=Integer.parseInt(txt2);

                int add=no1+no2;

                ans.setText(""+add);


                }
        }
        );

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
                String txt1=first.getText().toString();
                int no1=Integer.parseInt(txt1);
                String txt2=second.getText().toString();
                int no2=Integer.parseInt(txt2);


                int sub=no1-no2;

                ans.setText(""+sub);

                }
        }
        );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

        }
```

Layout(activity_main.xml)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hello.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/FirstNumber"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstnotxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/firstno"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstno"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstno"
        android:text="@string/SecondNumber"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondnotxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/secondno"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secondno"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/firstno"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondno"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondno"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/Subtract" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
    06-03 05:00:10.356: E/Trace(2903): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-03 05:00:10.818: D/AndroidRuntime(2903): Shutting down VM
06-03 05:00:10.818: W/dalvikvm(2903): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hello/com.example.hello.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at com.example.hello.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-03 05:00:10.916: E/AndroidRuntime(2903):     ... 11 more
06-03 05:00:14.086: I/Process(2903): Sending signal. PID: 2903 SIG: 9
06-03 05:01:01.957: E/Trace(2965): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-03 05:01:02.247: D/AndroidRuntime(2965): Shutting down VM
06-03 05:01:02.296: W/dalvikvm(2965): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hello/com.example.hello.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at com.example.hello.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-03 05:01:02.336: E/AndroidRuntime(2965):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: try to put some stack trace and piece of code to find out whats your problem

Comment: How does your application look like? Can you at least provide the relevant activity and xml files?

Comment: show your code and adb log

Comment: post your logCat and some of your mainActivity code to demonstrate the problem and it would be very helpful if u posted the manifest too

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `setContentView()` at first, then only you will get the components to assign or to add listeners.
 Try like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {   

private Button btn1, btn2;
private TextView ans;
private EditText first, second;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ans = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

    first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);
    second = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);

    listener();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't helped

Comment: Update your answer. If you have already declared global variables then no need to declare again in `onCreate()`

Comment: if it solves your problem .. please make it as answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize your your `Views` before `onCreate()` method otherwise it will throw null pointer exception because at first it will be null because view always initialize in `onCreate()` method.. Because first `super.onCreate()` calls. So you need to move all this

```
  private Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  private Button btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
  private TextView ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

  private EditText first =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);
  private EditText second =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstnotxt);
```

after    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`